# How do I call a powershell script using dollar-slashy from a jenkins pipeline and pass output to next stage

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, powercli

My Jenkins master runs on linux and I am attempting to run a stage containing powershell on a windows server.

I have been able to run Get-ChildItem and pass the output to the next stage but running vSphere PowerCLI cmdlets eludes me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def datacenter = ''

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage( 'PShell' ) {
            agent { label 'VmWareTools 2016' }
            steps {
                script {
                  def output = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: $/
                  try {
                      Import-Module KcsModule -Force
                      $VMWareCred = Read-CredentialFile mycreds.file
                      $VCenters = "VCenter1","VCenter2"
                      $VCenters | % { IF ($global:DefaultVIServers.Name -notcontains $_) { Connect-VIServer $_ -Credential $VMWareCred -WarningAction SilentlyContinue }}
                      ((Get-VM  $($env:VM)  |  where {$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn'}).Uid.Split('`@`:')[1])
                   } 
                   catch { echo "Unable to locate DataCenter" } 
                   finally { Disconnect-VIServer * -Force }
                /$)
                datacenter = output
                }
            }
        }
```

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: VMWareCred for
>   class:  WorkflowScript

Is it possible to have a Build Step job that invoke-command with a scriptblock and capture the output in a variable for use in the next stage?

Comment: Thank you Jeroen for editing my code.  I am still interested in the dollar-slashy approach but am moving forward with a seperate jenkins powershell job that will determine the datacenter and use vmtools to run a bash script on my target server.

Comment: If you are wanting to run PowerCLI then you would need to load the module into Powershell. Get the script working on the machine first then try making Jenkins use it.